# Change the speed or timeout of jQuery Cycle slides

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I added the jQuery Cycle Plugin to my website, and it works perfectly. I could add many of these cycle slides on one page, I placed them in blocks, some of the blocks have the cycle slides in and some don't. I just changed the id for each div and referenced it in the jQuery. But what I want to know is, how do I change the speed or timeout or delay for each of these cycle slides, I want it the same as the Windows 8 start up page, the one cycle slide is a bit slower than the other one, will this be the timeout or the speed? I want the one cycle slider to already go to the second image when the other cycle slider is still on the first image..

Answer (score 0):

You have the option `timeout` por the cycle... You already try?

> timeout:       4000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)

Comment: Ok cool, but will that apply to all the cycle slides, cause I have many of them on different places on my website, I have one at the bottom that is a slideshow and one at the top and middle, and I don't want it to apply to all of them, just one

Comment: You can do for each cycle... `$('#cycle1').cycle({ 
    timeout:  2000 
});
$('#cycle2').cycle({ 
    timeout:  3000 
});`

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
$('#element').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:   300, 
timeout: 3000,
});
```